# Spring-boot with spring secutiry error: There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i'm currently implementing security with spring-boot to my little API as a project to school of course nothing big but i wanted to manage some roles and stuff. 
I've been trying with adding .antMatchers(url).hasRole(someRole). ... more ant matchers ...
When testing log-in actualy show an error (type=Forbidden, status=403).

Here is some code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/control").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/", "/index","/img/*.jpg","/*.js","/*.css").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Bean 
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

Just a controller that shows my controlpanel to CRUD my animals :p

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/control")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private AnimalService animalService;

    @RequestMapping 
    public String getAnimals(Model model) { 

        List<Animal> animals = animalService.getAnimals();
        List<Animal> cats = new ArrayList<Animal>(); 
        List<Animal> dogs = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        List<Animal> bunnys = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        List<Animal> rats = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        animals.forEach(animal -> {

            animal.setStr(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(animal.getImg()));
            if (animal.getType().equals("cat")) {
                cats.add(animal);
            }
            if (animal.getType().equals("dog")) {
                dogs.add(animal);
            }
            if (animal.getType().equals("bunny")) {
                bunnys.add(animal);
            }
            if (animal.getType().equals("rat")) {
                rats.add(animal);
            }
        });
        model.addAttribute("cats", cats);
        model.addAttribute("dogs", dogs);
        model.addAttribute("bunnys", bunnys);
        model.addAttribute("rats", rats);
        return "control";
    }

}
```

I hope you guys can help me, im new with spring.

Comment: how r u tetsing this /control endpoint?

Comment: @pvpkiran web browser -> localhost:port/control

Comment: You have to login Frst.
For accessing this /control  url you have to a login user with ADMIN Role as you code.

Comment: As a side note, I strongly recommend using a `Map<String, List<Animal>>` isntead of your parallel lists; it will make your code much simpler and more reliable. Additionally, get in the habit of using constructor injection, not field injection, which is the modern best practice.

Answer (score 0):

[DB tuple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTDfe.png)

Re: it was as simple as save the role in de DB as the follows:
ROLE_roleNAME